# Vlookup error in the first parameter

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem in my code. I want to look for a value from another a sheet and then copy it in the active sheet but the problem is that my condition is inside a loop.It gives me an error in Vlookup line. Can someone detect me the error:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan Traitement Risque")
    For i = 6 To lr1 Step 1
      'Test si valeur cellule feuil1!=Ax est dans Plage col_2(feuil2!A1:A50))
    If Application.CountIf(col_2, .Range("B" & i).Value) = 0 Then
     Cells(i, 3).Select
     ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(Cells(i, 2).Value,'Scénarios de menace'!$B$6:$N$700,2,FALSE)"
    End If
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The active cell formula is built as a string. If you want to pass it a VBA function like `cells(a, b).value` into that string, you need to concatenate that with the other parts of the string, like this:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""" & Cells(i, 2).Value & """,'Scénarios de menace'!$B$6:$N$700,2,FALSE)"
```

Edit: added quotes to accommodate a string in cells(i,2), as suggested in a comment by Jeeped.

Comment: It resolve a part of the problem, it recognize the type but when I debug it gives me that : Vlookup(#NOM?;'Scénarios de menace'!$B$6:$N$700,2,FALSE) ...

Comment: what does `Cells(i, 2).Value` return? Is "#NOM?" the same as the #Name? error in English Excel? If so, Excel thinks that it is dealing with a function or a range name that it can't resolve. `Cells(i, 2).Value` should return the value you want to look up.

Comment: @Souma - Probably a string value that has to be in quotes (or double-quotes inside  a quoted string). Something like `... = "=VLOOKUP(""" & Cells(i, 2).Value & """,...`

Comment: @teylyn : Yes it's the same thing that #Name, that means there is an error in the second parameter of vlookup "'Scénarios de menace'!$B$6:$N$700" ??

Comment: Jeeped probably hits it on the head. I have adjusted the code above.

Comment: @Jeeped, teylyn : Thank you both for your help, I modified my code by adding " " ", but now it gives me 0 as a result " This formula is different from the other formulas in this sheet.

Comment: The VBA has written a formula into the cell. What is that formula? If it is a valid Vlookup and the result is 0, that means the Vlookup is pointed to an empty cell. Find the lookup value in the lookup table and check the data.